# Shiny server and client

Tags: r

I am using RStudio server with shiny to create apps.  I am struggling with the concept of server and client.  As I understand it, please correct me if I am wrong, the RStudio server installtion provides a server.  I cannot find the server directories.  I see that when I create the folders in my unix machine, they appear on the right hand side panel when I click on the files tab.  I wonder if the local folders are reproduced in the RStudio server.

For this reason, I do not understand how to upload a file from my pc to the Rstudio server, and how to download a file from the RStudio server to my machine and save it to in a folder in my machime (Ubuntu 17.04).

Could someone point me in the right direction?  what should I read, what libraries/packages should I use to code the functionality?

Thanks
gccd

Comment: This seems general enough that you should say where in the tutorial things have gone wrong for you. https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/

Comment: I have uploaded the file, but I cannot save it in the server:  please see code

Comment: There is no code here. It is unclear what you are asking, exactly. What in the docs and turorials is missing? Are you trying to deploy an app? Are you trying to develop and test? Instead of asking about where some files are supposed to go, state what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get and you are more likely to get help.

Comment: Is this also you? https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-server-and-client/3917 Seems like someone has answered.

Comment: Two things, Are you running windows or Linux on your machine? Either way google something like "copy files over ssh."  For windows users putty works pretty well for moving files between your machine and the server. Second R Shiny Server is separate from R Studio Server, you need a Shiny server not a R studio server to deploy a shiny app.

Comment: This is an answer I previously provided some of it may be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527041/run-r-shiny-app-on-apache-server/43528264#43528264

Comment: At the top of the files pane next to New Folder. Pressing the upload will bring up another dialog to upload files from your local machine to the current user’s directory on the server. Under the More button, you’ll find export to download files from the server to your local machine. How can I acces…

Comment: so, the file is uploaded from the local machine to the current user's directory on the server.  That is what I believed when I posted the first question.  I have uploaded that file using fileUpload() and save it using copy.file).  Now I would like to know how to get access to the server and see the file to downloaded to the local linux machine using the shiny download functionality

Answer (score 0):

This code works correctly.  It downloads the file from the server to the local directory.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "params" = params)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({ 
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.table(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}
```